# Jboss mod_cluster configuration for loadbalancer

Tags: jboss, load-balancing, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7, mod-cluster

I am new to jboss and i am learning how the loadbalancer works in our application.
There are two clusters and each server has **two eap**, from four eap's , **two are used for bpm**.
From domain.xml of jboss eap 6.4 i have this

*

```
<mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp">
                    <dynamic-load-provider>
                        <load-metric type="busyness"/>
                    </dynamic-load-provider>
</mod-cluster-config>
```

*
and for jboss eap 7.0 for bpm i have

```
<mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp">
                    <dynamic-load-provider>
                        <load-metric type="cpu"/>
                    </dynamic-load-provider>
                </mod-cluster-config>
```

I am not able to get a lot of information on mod_cluster.

It would be really helpful if anyone would tell me how the mod_cluster is configured and how it works. Any helps or suggestions are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`<load-metric type="busyness"/>` and `<load-metric type="cpu"/>` are nothing but load metric algorithm that is provided in Jboss for manipulating requests between load servers.
[Load Metric Algorithm](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.2/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/configure_the_mod_cluster_subsystem)

For your requirement , use the [link](https://modcluster.io/examples/#jboss-as-instances-in-domain-mode-with-mod_cluster-load-balancer) as start up guide . It is self explanatory . Kindly modify the configuration to suit your need . Please add comments for any bottlenecks or errors.